# MySQL Category tree

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this MySQL tabel and I'm trying to get the ids of the main category and each subcategory linked to it and the others linked to this subcategories... You can see an example below:

```
+----------------------+
| Catrgorias           |
+----------------------+
| id (int 11)          |
+----------------------+
| nombre (varchar 255) |
+----------------------+
| parent (int 11)      |
+----------------------+
+----+------------+--------+
| id | nombre     | parent |
+----+------------+--------+
| 1  | Cat1       | NULL   |
+----+------------+--------+
| 2  | Cat2.      | NULL   |
+----+------------+--------+
| 3  | SubCat1    | 1      |
+----+------------+--------+
| 4  | SubCat2    | 2      |
+----+------------+--------+
| 5  | SubSubCat1 | 3      |
+----+------------+--------+
```

Does anyone know how to get these ids in MySQL and get this result with something like this?

For categort_tree(1)

```
+----+     +-------+
| id |     | id    |
+----+  or +-------+
| 1  |     | 1,3,5 |
+----+     +-------+
| 3  |
+----+
| 5  |
+----+
```

For categort_tree(2)

```
+----+     +-----+
| id |     | id  |
+----+  or +-----+
| 2  |     | 2,4 |
+----+     +-----+
| 4  |
+----+
```

Comment: Umm --  `SELECT id FROM Catrgorias`  will get you the first result you are looking for .. Unless I am missing something? ..

Comment: I've corrected the question to explain it better. I'm trying to get the main category id and the id of the categorias wich have it as parent and the subcategorias wich have as parent a category linket to the main etc.

Comment: you need to use a recursive cte to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a recursive CTE

```
with cte as
(
   SELECT ID
   FROM CATEGORY 
   WHERE ID = %input

   UNION ALL

   SELECT ID
   FROM CATEGORY 
   JOIN CTE ON PARENT = CTE.ID
)
SELECT * FROM CTE
```

Comment: I can't do it becaus of the mariaDB version. The with statement was introduced in mariaDB 10.2.1 and my server is currently using version 10.0.37. There is another option?

Comment: @Pablocarrió -- nope.  recursive is the only way.  Unless you only want to go a specific number of levels deep.